# Некорректные пути к файлам

Tags: html, gulp

Есть сборка gulp, все вроде работает, но когда я загружаю zip архив, что бы отдать заказчику просто не подгружаются css стили и картинки, хотя пути указаны правильно, что делать?

Например:

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="img" />
```

Отрываю index.html в самом архиве и ее просто нет, так же со стилями.
Пробовал указывать полный путь

```
<img src="D:/blablabla/dist/images/logo.png" alt="img" />
```

Тогда работает, но это как то странно, короче, что делать?

Вот сама сборка:

```
let project_folder = 'dist';
let source_folder = '#src';

let path = {
    build: {
        html: project_folder + '/',
        css: project_folder + '/css/',
        js: project_folder + '/js/',
        img: project_folder + '/images/',
        fonts: project_folder + '/fonts/',
    },
    src: {
        html: [source_folder + '/*.html', '!' + source_folder + '/_*.html'],
        css: source_folder + '/scss/main.scss',
        js: source_folder + '/js/script.js',
        img: source_folder + '/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|ico|svg|webp)',
        fonts: source_folder + '/fonts/*.ttf',
    },
    watch: {
        html: source_folder + '/**/*.html',
        css: source_folder + '/scss/**/*.scss',
        js: source_folder + '/js/**/*.js',
        img: source_folder + '/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|ico|svg|webp)',
    },
    clean: './' + project_folder + '/',
};

let { src, dest } = require('gulp'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    browsersync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
    del = require('del'),
    scss = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    group_media = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries'),
    clean_css = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default,
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    webp = require('gulp-webp'),
    webphtml = require('gulp-webp-html'),
    webpcss = require('gulp-webpcss'),
    ttf2woff = require('gulp-ttf2woff'),
    ttf2woff2 = require('gulp-ttf2woff2'),
    fonter = require('gulp-fonter');

function browserSync(params) {
    browsersync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './' + project_folder + '/',
        },
        port: 3000,
        notify: false,
    });
}

function html() {
    return src(path.src.html).pipe(fileinclude()).pipe(webphtml()).pipe(dest(path.build.html)).pipe(browsersync.stream());
}

function css() {
    return src(path.src.css)
        .pipe(scss({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }))
        .pipe(group_media())
        .pipe(
            autoprefixer({
                cascade: true,
                overrideBrowserslist: ['last 5 versions'],
            })
        )
        .pipe(
            webpcss({
                webpClass: '.webp',
                noWebpClass: '.no-webp',
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(clean_css())
        .pipe(
            rename({
                extname: '.min.css',
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}

function js() {
    return src(path.src.js)
        .pipe(fileinclude())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(
            rename({
                extname: '.min.js',
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}

function images() {
    return src(path.src.img)
        .pipe(
            webp({
                quality: 70,
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
        .pipe(src(path.src.img))
        .pipe(
            imagemin({
                progressive: true,
                svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
                interlaced: true,
                optimizationLevel: 3, // 0 to 7
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}

function fonts() {
    src(path.src.fonts).pipe(ttf2woff()).pipe(dest(path.build.fonts));
    return src(path.src.fonts).pipe(ttf2woff2()).pipe(dest(path.build.fonts));
}

gulp.task('otf2ttf', function () {
    return src([source_folder + '/fonts/*.otf'])
        .pipe(
            fonter({
                formats: ['ttf'],
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(source_folder + '/fonts/'));
});

function fontsStyle(params) {
    let file_content = fs.readFileSync(source_folder + '/scss/_fonts.scss');
    if (file_content == '') {
        fs.writeFile(source_folder + '/scss/_fonts.scss', '', cb);
        return fs.readdir(path.build.fonts, function (err, items) {
            if (items) {
                let c_fontname;
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    let fontname = items[i].split('.');
                    fontname = fontname[0];
                    if (c_fontname != fontname) {
                        fs.appendFile(source_folder + '/scss/_fonts.scss', '@include font("' + fontname + '", "' + fontname + '", "400", "normal");\r\n', cb);
                    }
                    c_fontname = fontname;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

function cb() {}

function watchFiles(params) {
    gulp.watch([path.watch.html], { usePolling: true }, html);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.css], { usePolling: true }, css);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.js], { usePolling: true }, js);

    gulp.watch;

    gulp.watch([path.watch.img], { usePolling: true }, images);
}

function clean(params) {
    return del(path.clean);
}

let build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(js, css, html, images, fonts), fontsStyle);
let watch = gulp.parallel(build, watchFiles, browserSync);

exports.fontsStyle = fontsStyle;
exports.fonts = fonts;
exports.images = images;
exports.js = js;
exports.css = css;
exports.html = html;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;

gulp.watch;
```

Comment: *когда я загружаю zip архив, что бы отдать заказчику просто не подгружаются css стили и картинки, хотя пути указаны правильно* Да? а откуда такая уверенность, что текущий каталог - именно "D:/blablabla/dist/"?

Comment: Я надеюсь вы не из zip архива html открываете?

Comment: Никогда не открывайте, как вы выразились "в самом архиве". Распакуйте. Иначе система при открытие временно распаковывает только один файл, тот что вы открыли. Без остальных, которые вам нужны.

Comment: @RavenTheX из него )

Comment: Так разархивируйте сначала его))

Comment: @Pavel Zabelin спасибо огромное

Comment: @RavenTheX ахпзпза, ладно, понял))0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала разархивируйте папку с вашими файлами, система видит только тот файл что вы открыли

Comment: *система видит только тот файл что вы открыли* - у gulp свой разархиватор? ибо если не переопределять обработчик для ZIP и общаться с ним как со "сжатой папкой", то прекрасно видны все файлы, а не только текущий открытый.